# Android Admob Upgrade now showing ads

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm having issues since upgrading to the new admob.

Ads were displaying 100% perfect, and now they aren't displaying at all since upgrading...they said NO CODING changes were needed-

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you see in the log? Is the ad coming through at all or is the ad not showing since the fill rate is low and there is essentially no ad to display?

Answer (score 0):

No coding changes **are** required. See PravinCG's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem after upgrading to the new admob, but it works fine now. Take a look at [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/prAlwDafFBs):

"We’ve seen a small number of migrated publishers receive fill rates lower than usual after upgrading. We’ve identified the cause and rolled out a fix today. If you need further help, please contact us via the form in the Help Center."

I hope in the meanwhile it works for you as well :)